# Is this a safe way to use ajax in wordpress to fetch content?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, security, nonce

Here is some working code for a promo modal but is this a safe and appropriate way to use the wordpress nonce in an ajax request?

Create the nonce in the tmp: $ajax_nonce = wp_create_nonce( "mynonce" );
Example URL: www.mysite.com/#345345

```
var asdf = location.hash.match(/^#?(.*)$/)[1];
if (asdf) {
    $productID = asdf; 
    if ($.cookie("modalshow") === undefined) {
        var expiryDate = new Date();
        var minutes = 0.20; //12 seconds
        expiryDate.setTime(expiryDate.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000)); 
        $.cookie("modalshow", "exists", { path: '/', expires: expiryDate });
        var data = {
            action: 'my_action',
            product_id: $productID,
            security: '<?php echo $ajax_nonce; ?>'
        };
        var ajaxurl = '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                $(".modal-content").append(response);
                $('#Modal').modal({ show:true });
        });
    } //no cookie
};//if match
```

Plugin:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_function' );
function my_action_function() {
    check_ajax_referer( 'mynonce', 'security' );
    if( isset($_POST['product_id']) ) {
        $my_report_num = $_POST['product_id']; // splash 443
        $myposttype = get_post_type( $my_product_num );
        if ( get_post_status( $my_product_num ) == 'publish' && $myposttype == "df_product" ) {
            //we're good
            $theid = $my_product_num;
        } else {
            $theid = "876";
        }
        //fedtch content using $theid
        die();
        } // end if
    die;
}
```

In the above php, get_post_type() uses get_post() which uses sanitize_post() - so there is some validation being done, and currently my plan is that if anything malicious is appended to the URL or sent by some other means in the client, that $theid will be set to my white listed number "876" - so do I need to do additional validation either in the client or in php?

Any assistance is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Well, it's the way WordPress does it, although your parameters to wp_verify_nonce are wrong. The first parameter is the string you used to create the nonce ('mynonce'). The second parameter is the query **arg**, not the value, so should be 'nonce'.

Comment: Above code edited in response to bobdye - thanks for the feedback - changed from $.ajax to $.post and using check_ajax_referrer() rather than wp_verify_nonce();
Is this a better way of doing it?